404 not found pop up browser after deploying server only

//server file
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const PORT = 5000;


app.get('/',(req,res)=>{

  res.send("<h2>free tibet</h2>")
})


app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
  console.log(`server listening to ${PORT}`);
})

anyone face similar problem? help appreciated, thanks in advance

oh i forgot i deploy it on vercel
